# Is there a way to join two queries on SQL (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to join two queries A and B on BigQuery.

**Query A**

```
SELECT membership_no, first_name, surname 
FROM `some.Table1`
```

**Query B**

```
SELECT membership_no, membership_class, membership_status, join_date
FROM `some.Table2`
WHERE join_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
AND membership_status = 'ACTIVE'
```

Is there a short and elegant way of joining two existing queries?
A kin to...

```
SELECT *
FROM (A)
JOIN
(B)
USING (membership_no)
```

without having to write codes for the A and B?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you simply want to create views for each of your queries?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Sorry, I don't think I am describing well here...
Query A and Query B are already there. 
Would there be a simple short way to create a new query that returns the combined results of two queries? (i.e. show all details of active member from year 2019 in this case)

Comment: @cocneyninja . . . Interesting.  I am not aware of a way to refer to the result of an unnamed historical query.  You can go to the query history and save the result set in a table and use that in a subsequent query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks, it seems there's now way to refer to the result of saved query at the moment on BigQuery. Your method works as well. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH queryA AS (
  SELECT membership_no, first_name, surname 
  FROM `some.Table1`
), queryB AS (
  SELECT membership_no, membership_class, membership_status, join_date
  FROM `some.Table2`
  WHERE join_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
AND membership_status = 'ACTIVE'
)
SELECT *
FROM queryA
JOIN queryB
USING (membership_no)
```

Comment: Thank you!
I was wondering if I can somehow call the saved queries without having to write the codes again. 
Is that possible?

Comment: no, there is no way to access saved queries as of today! there is respective ticket opened so you can find it and vote up if you also (as many of us) want to have such API

Comment: Thank you, I feel marginally less silly now. Could you give me a link to the ticket - need to cast my vote as well!

Comment: sure - [REST API for Saved Queries](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111961970)